# finding words within String and returning as String + spaces Java

Tags: java

I've been practicing on Codewars to improve my programming but am stuck on this 
problem, i.e.:

-need to go through a String and take out the "Wub" and "Dub" in order to

-present the English language words inside the String

-in a String separated by a space

eg. The output here should be:
we are the champions my friends

I find myself unable to 
-convert the Character array list into a string adequately
-identify the words and separate by a space

I hope I've explained this adequately, thanks in advance.

```
public class Dubstep {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(SongDecoder("WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB"));
}

public static String SongDecoder(String song) {
    String name = song;
    ArrayList<Character> words = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < song.length(); i++) {

        if (name.charAt(i) == 'W' && name.charAt(i + 1) == 'U' && name.charAt(i + 2) == 'B') {
            i = i + 2;
        } else { 
             words.add(name.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    String result = words.toString();
    return result;
}
}
///expected:
///we are the champions my friends
///actual:
///[W, E, A, R, E, T, H, E, C, H, A, M, P, I, O, N, S, M, Y, F, R, I, E, N, D]
```

Solution offered:

```
public class dubStepv2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(SongDecoder("WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB"));
}
public static String SongDecoder(String song) {
    String originalString = song;

    String newString = originalString.replace("WUB", " ");
   newString = newString.replace("DUB", " ");
    newString = newString.trim();

    return newString;
}
}
///Output:
///WE ARE  THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND
///Expected:
///WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND
```

Answer (score 2):

A very much simpler way would be to use [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) and [`String::trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim())

```
newString = "WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB"
        .replace("WUB", " ")
        .replace("DUB", " ")
        .trim();
```

replacing with a blank and to remove leading and trailing blanks.

Comment: One would have to replace both with a blank and then - in a last pass - replace multiple repeated blanks with one blank.

Comment: Thanks kindly but I'm afraid this leaves 2 spaces within the string output, have updated the OP to reflect

Comment: @Cammo5000 If that is is the case, then I would have thought it would be easy enough to do a `replace ("  ", " ")` to replace two spaces with one.